# Sage Accpac Ireport method failed

Tags: methods, accpac

We had a macros developed in our company that used to export files to an Excel format and then inserted those values in the *Sage ACCPAC Payroll* module. For some reason the code has stopped to respond, and it gives an error: `method ireport of accpac.ireport failed`

Here is the code:

```
rpt.NumOfCopies = 1
rpt.Format = PF_NONE
rpt.Destination = PD_FILE
rpt.PrintDir = "[\\hcc-acc\Accpac\Macros\Reports and Macros\Tax\Test]"

rpt.PrintReport
```

As soon as it comes to `rpt.PrintReport`, it gives an error. I will be absolutely grateful for  any help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the name of the PDF file in the rpt.PrintDir parameter:

```
rpt.PrintDir = "[\\hcc-acc\Accpac\Macros\Reports and Macros\Tax\Test\SomeFileName.PDF]"
```